# Karate: How to iterate through JSON payload and print length of values of each field

Tags: karate

I have a requirement where I want to print the character length of the values of all fields in JSON payload.

For example payload is:

```
{
  "request": {
    "tranRef": "1234",
    "sender": {
      "firstName": "Johnny",
      "lastName": "Doe",
      "address": {
        "city": "Arlington",
        "country": "USA"
      },
      "organizationName": "Unity"
    },
    "type": "Merchant"
  }
} 


it would print something like
 tranRef >> 4
 sender.firstName >> 6
 sender.lastName >> 3
 sender.address.city >> 9  
 sender.address.country >> 3
 sender.organizationName >> 5
 type >> 8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not supported. Write your own [Java interop code](https://github.com/intuit/karate#calling-java) or you might be able to get somewhere with the JSON transforms: https://github.com/intuit/karate#json-transforms

Karate is a testing framework, not a general purpose programming language.